# Left Outer Joins, WHERE clause and COALESCE

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have three tables:

```
Users:                  Depts                   Default
| fid | uid | rights |  | fid | did | rights |  | fid | rights |
|-----+-----+--------|  |-----+-----+--------|  |-----+--------|
|  1  |  1  |   4    |  |  1  | 10  |    2   |  |  1  |   2    |
|  3  |  1  |   4    |  |  2  | 10  |    2   |  |  2  |   4    |
+--------------------+  +--------------------+  +--------------+
```

These define the access rights a user has to a file in the system based on their user ID and the department of which they are a member. When accessing a file the effective rights are determined in order by the default rights (if any), which are overridden by the departmental rights (if any), which are in turn overridden by the user permissions, if any.

Thus, in this example, user 1, member of department 10, has no user rights for file 2, but gains rights level 2 from his department. (Default rights of 4 don't apply because they're overridden by departmental rights)

I need to query this table structure to determine the effective rights of a user for one or more files. Initially, my only requirement was to obtain the effective rights for one file at a time which I did by assigning a priority to each of three subqueries, combining them with a `UNION` in order of priority, and then taking only the first result, like this:

```
select a.rights from 
    (select 100 as priority, rights from `Users` where `uid`=1 and `fid` = 2 union 
    select 200 as priority, rights from `Depts` where `did`=10 and `fid` = 2 union 
    select 300 as priority, rights from `Default` where `fid` = 2
            ) as a 
            order by priority asc limit 1;
```

Now, this may not be particularly efficient, but it has served so far.

---

My problem now is to extend this to retrieve a user's effective rights for more than one files. Because of the priority structure this simply can't be done with the existing query.

I should be able to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` across the three tables to produce a set of rights values I can `COALESCE`, but MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`

After some digging around on Stack Overflow and elsewhere I arrived at this (UID, Dept ID and File Id are illustrative only):

```
select u.fid as fid, u.rights as urights, d.rights as drights, def.rights as defRights 
from 
  (users as u 
    left outer join Depts as d using (fid)
    left outer join Default as def using (fid))  
    where fid in (21, 1823, 1830) and dept_id=10 and uid=1
  union
    select u.fid as fid, u.rights as urights, d.rights as drights, def.rights as defRights 
    from 
      (Depts as d
      left outer join Users as u using (fid)
      left outer join Default as def using (fid))
      where fid in (21, 1823, 1830) and dept_id=10 and uid=1
  union
    select u.fid as fid, u.rights as urights, d.rights as drights, def.rights as defRights 
    from 
      (Default as def 
      left outer join Users as u using (fid)
      left outer join Depts as d using (fid))
      where fid in (21, 1823, 1830) and dept_id=10 and uid=1
```

Superficially, this appeared to work, but the use of the `WHERE` clause is filtering the results incorrectly. From my reading it seems that using an `ON` clause might be the solution, but getting the syntax right has defeated me.

For our example of file #2 above I should expect to get

```
| fid | Users | Depts | Default |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
|  2  | null  |   2   |    4    |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+
```

This should give effective rights of 2 when the three rights values are coalesced.

This query may well work for this simple example. The problem that emerged in testing is that some files that should be included weren't.

---

So, my question is this:

How can I write the query I have with `ON` clauses instead of `WHERE`?

As a bonus, is there a better way of achieving the same result?

As a footnote: this entire structure needs to be reviewed in time, but that time is not now. This is what I have to work with until some later development prompts us to implement something better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Bon appetit.  You just got yourself a challenging question.

Comment: is there something that specifies what dept a user is in?

Comment: @pala_ There's a separate user table that gives that information. The file table carries similar information for each file. I don't really see how that would help.The code that handles the rights tables doesn't have access to those tables, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an inline view of all the files you are interested in by unioning them together, instead of using `where in`.  This will maintain the `outer`nish of the query chain

eg:

```
select files.fid, u.rights, d.rights, def.rights
  from (
    select 1 as fid
    union all
    select 2 as fid
    union all
    select 3 as fid
    -- all the files you are interested in
  ) files
  left join users u
    on files.fid = u.fid
      and u.uid = 2         -- put the user you are searching for here
  left join depts d
    on files.fid = d.fid
      and d.did = 10        -- put the dept you are searching for here
  left join `default` def
    on files.fid = def.fid
```

[quick demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e75b0/4)

Comment: The number of files may be small for some queries, but I need this to be able to handle hundreds of files. I could generate the required SELECT statements programatically, but I can't help but think there must be a better way.

Comment: @HoboSapiens i assumed that since you would have been programmatically including them in the `where in`, then it would have been a small matter to construct the unions instead.  Alternatively the only way i can see it happening is if you have a table of all the files as well?

Comment: It's late today. I'll take a look at it again in the morning and see if your solution is workable.

Comment: That was too easy. It simply hadn't occurred to me to break out the file IDs that way. As you say, I can pre-process the SELECT statements for the file IDs in PHP. The query has to cope with potentially hundreds of files. Is there likely to be any benefit in creating a temporary table to hold the file IDs, or is this something that I'd need to experiment with?

Comment: If the files are a known quantity, then yeah i'd probably create a table to hold them and index the `fid`

Comment: No - the file Ids will vary from query to query. Most queries will be just one file ID , but a significant number could be any size, and the required Id(s) are likely to be different each time. I'll run with this for now and look at caching the results or tweaking the query if performance demands it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem - what I did mean was a single table of all files, which you can then limit with `where`. It might be worth looking at if this becomes cumbersome